# I can't login ubuntu 22.04 GUI with my domain user without network connection

Tags: networking, ssh, ubuntu-gnome, domain-server

Now I have two issues:In my ubuntu

1. When my computer is not in the network, I can't login GUI with my domain user ID.
2. I am uanble to sudo su with domain account when I am in Network with gui Login.

Comment: "Your domain userid" must connect with your domain controller to validate your password.  No internet, no connection to the domain  controller, no password validation.